# ping -r results are confusing

Tags: ping

As you know, "**ping -r**" displays hops (maximum 9 hops) between your computer and destination (as **tracert** does).

Using this command, in many cases, I get "request timeOut" (first pic) while by using simple ping command, I get all the replies (second pic).

Note, based on my captures, there is no difference between packets generated by "ping -r" and simple ping commands.

Now, why??!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

ping -r adds RECORD_ROUTE flags in packet which many hosts ignoring this flag.
Is not recommended tool to check path route. I would use instead traceroute or mtr. And is only supporting up to 9 hops. If destination is farther than 9 hops this will fail. As manual says:

```
>      -R     Record route. (IPv4 only) Includes the RECORD_ROUTE option in the ECHO_REQUEST packet and displays the route buffer on  returned 
> packets.   Note
>               that the IP header is only large enough for nine such routes.  Many hosts ignore or discard this option.
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/option007.htm
please read this page for find out why look like it has a security issue for the destination to do that for you.

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged because links may change over time, or go away completely. You should quote the relevant portions from the link, and include the link to give proper attribution to the author(s).